# How to set unique constraint over multiple columns when any one can be null?

Tags: sqlite

How do I set unique constraint over multiple columns when any one can be null in SQLite?

e.g. I have made `unique("col1","col2","col3")` and tried `insert into tablename values("abc","def",null)` twice it inserted both rows.

The unique constraint is not working when third column is null.

Answer (score 5):

In sqlite, all null are differences.
I think the best way to solve this issue is to set column c not null with a special default value. Then use the default value (for example 0, '') to represent null.

## edit 1

you can easily extend this solution to any columns

```
create table test (
    a text not null default "",
    b text not null default "",
    c text not null default ""
);
```

Comment: It is not necessary that only col c can null ,any column can be null . e.g. it can be ("abc",null,"def").

Comment: you can easily extend this solution to any columns

Comment: giving not null to that column is not the solution coz these values can be null. I am reading from xml and entering in to table . null value is acceptable . my problem is if one row value is ("a","b",null) and other row is also have ("a","b",null), then it should not enter in table while given unique constraint to these columns. I have defined unique("col1","col2","col3").One more thing if I am entering ("a","b","c") for two rows then my unique constraint is working fine but if any col value is null then my unique constraint is not working.

Comment: The unique constraint will not work with `null` value in sqlite. but it didn't stop you to use other value to replace it. It is a common way to solve this kind of problem. just remember to translate them back to null value while you retrieve value from sqlite.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with version 3.9.0 (2015-10-14) you can use indexes on expressions (https://www.sqlite.org/expridx.html) and use for example the `COALESCE` function to transform `null` values into some form of fallback value:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_Unique ON Table1 (
    COALESCE(col1, ""), 
    COALESCE(col2, ""), 
    COALESCE(col3, "")
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a trigger to enfore this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER col1_col2_col3null_unique
BEFORE INSERT ON MyTable
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN col1 IS NOT NULL
 AND col2 IS NOT NULL
 AND col3 IS NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'col1/col2/col3 must be unique')
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE col1 = NEW.col1
      AND col2 = NEW.col2
      AND col3 IS NULL;
END;
```

You need such a trigger for each possible combination of NULLs in the three columns.
Furthermore, if it is possible to have UPDATEs that change such a column to NULL, you need triggers for those, too.