# unique index constraint not being enforced for NULL

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have created a table in my sqlite database with a composite unique index constraint. The problem is that the constraint is not being enforced. I am able to insert multiple rows with the same unique key(col2 NOT NULL,col4) of ("testvalue",NULL).

According to the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html),

`For the purposes of UNIQUE constraints, NULL values are considered distinct from all other values, including other NULLs.`

So then how do i enforce a unique constraint with NULL values?

Here's the class that describes my table :

```
public class myTable{
    /*table name*/
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "myTable";

    /*column names*/
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_1 = "col1";
    public static final String COLUMN_2 = "col2";
    public static final String COLUMN_3 = "col3";
    public static final String COLUMN_4 = "col4";

    /*create table script*/
    public static final String CREATE_TABLE = 
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME
        + "( " + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT"
        + ", " + COLUMN_1 + " INTEGER"
        + ", " + COLUMN_2 + " INTEGER NOT NULL"
        + ", " + COLUMN_3 + " TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
        + ", " + COLUMN_4 + " TEXT"
        + ", FOREIGN KEY(" + COLUMN_2 + ") REFERENCES " + Table_other.TABLE_NAME + "(" + Table_other.COLUMN_ID + ")"
        + ", FOREIGN KEY(" + COLUMN_1 + ") REFERENCES " + Table_yetanother.TABLE_NAME + "(" + Table_yetanother.COLUMN_ID + ")"
        + ")";

    /*create index script */
    public static final String CREATE_INDEX =   
        "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UIDX ON " + TABLE_NAME 
        + "(" + COLUMN_2 + "," + COLUMN_4 + ");";


}
```

Comment: See [NULL Handling in SQLite Versus Other Database Engines](http://www.sqlite.org/nulls.html) for more details.

Comment: @CL. thanks. that's a nice article. i had gone through that but i am still looking for a solution. I guess the only way is here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/12095133/2105986

Answer (score -1):

SQLite has foreign key constraints turned off by default.

You have to explicitly turn it on by doing the following:

```
// Enable foreign key constraints
if (!db.isReadOnly()) {
    db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;");
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: This does not resolve my issue but you have got my attention! Is this true for the SQlite version in Android as well? Do i run this PRAGMA command everytime i do an insert or once when i create/update the database?

Comment: @faizal You need to call [setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled%28boolean%29) in [onCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onConfigure%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase%29).

Comment: @CL. that's interesting. I assume you meant `onConfigure()`, not `onCreate()`. But this method and the `onConfigure()` callback was introduced in API 16. So, for older Android API versions, I could explicitly run the PRAGMA command. But where would i do it? I rule out `onCreate()` and `onUpgrade()` methods in my extended `SQLiteOpenHelper` class because they are not called when the database is opened every time. So i should execute this command in all my methods after `getWritableDatabase()` ?

Comment: (Well, I *linked* to `onConfigure()`. ☺) `onConfigure()` is more useful for things like [PRAGMA page_size](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_page_size) that must be executed *before* the database file is created. You can run `setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled()` at any time.