# Unique index when one of two columns is null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unique-constraint, database-indexes

(Rails 4.2.1, Sqlite3) I have three models - M1, M2, M3.

M1 belongs_to M2

M1 also belongs_to M3

M1 has a :name (string) field.

I have the following constraints that must be validated:

1) An M1 record can have an M2 or M3 associated, but not both.

2) M1 name must be unique under whichever of M2 or M3 is specified.

I have implemented constraint (1) in the model, and it works as expected. (I mention it only because it may be relevant to the scenario).

For constraint (2), I added an index in a migration as follows:

```
add_index :m1s, [:name, :m2_id, :m3_id], unique: true, name: "idx_m1_name"
```

Then I call:

```
> m2 = M2.create! # success
> m1_1 = M1.create!(name: 'm1_1', m2: m2) #success
> m1_2 = M1.create!(name: 'm1_1', m2: m2) # this line should fail, but doesn't
```

m1_1 and m1_2 get created - I expect that m1_2 should fail due to the uniqueness constraint.

I checked that the index does get added as expected. Also, as per constraint 1, m3_id is nil in both m1_1 and m1_2, not sure if it is relevant.

Why is the constraint not being checked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So `m3_id` is `NULL` in both cases ? In Sqlite3, a null value is considered distinct to another null value in the context of a unique index.

> For the purposes of unique indices, all NULL values are considered to
>   different from all other NULL values and are thus unique

See https://sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html

I think it's the same in MySQL and Postgres too.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected the null value, but your response and the link confirms it:-) ! So how do I verify the uniqueness constraint (2) above in the database?

Comment: hmm, so you can have M2 or M3, but not both. Have you considered using polymorphic relationships instead ? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12094479/how-to-set-unique-constraint-over-multiple-column-when-any-one-can-be-null-in-sq is possible too, but hacky

Comment: Polymorphic doesn't work for my scenario. I have something like a blog with nested posts. So, M1 is like a post,  M2 is like a blog,  and M3 is in fact a parent post. So a post can be a root post in a blog or it can be a child post of another post,but it cannot be both.

Comment: And yes, I agree that the other one is hacky. I might land up creating a validation in the model in rails rather than change the default null values. I cannot really make these some other values because both are foreign key ids,  and seeing them as not null will trigger all kinds of problems. This must be a fairly common problem. I wonder if there is some elegant way to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can express this with two indices.

```rb
add_index :m1s, [:name, :m2_id], unique: true
add_index :m1s, [:name, :m3_id], unique: true
```

Since nulls are considered distinct for uniqueness purposes, the first index will not constrain rows where only `m3_id` is set, and vice versa for the second index.

(You might also be interested in a [`CHECK` constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp) that checks that exactly one of `m2_id` or `m3_id` is null. In Rails, `CHECK` constraints have the minor caveat of [requiring the schema file to be expressed in SQL](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#reverting-previous-migrations). For a more general solution to "indices that only apply to some rows", see [partial indices](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_index-label-Creating+a+partial+index).)

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. The two indices approach will succeed even when both m2_id and m3_id are null. Requiring the schema to be in SQL seems too much for the current problem, so CHECK constraint doesn't work.

Comment: You can check that both aren't null in a Rails validation. Such a validation is not prone to races [like uniqueness validations are](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations). I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/23083) about the CHECK constraints.