# Composite unique contstraint with null values

Tags: sql, sqlite, unique-constraint

How can I set a composite unique constraint that can properly handle null values in SQLite? This is likely better expressed by example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE people (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    last_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    suffix TEXT,
    UNIQUE (first_name, last_name, suffix)
);
```

The constraint works as expected when a person with a suffix is entered more than once.

```sql
-- Last insert is denied
INSERT INTO people (first_name, last_name, suffix)
VALUES
    ('Joe', 'Dirt', 'Sr'),
    ('Joe', 'Dirt', 'Jr'),
    ('Joe', 'Dirt', 'Sr');
```

However, the unique constraint is not accommodating when a person without a suffix is inserted more than once.

```sql
-- Both are permitted
INSERT INTO people (first_name, last_name)
VALUES
    ('Chris', 'Farley'),
    ('Chris', 'Farley');
```

I understand SQLite treats null values as independent from one another, but is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to set unique constraint over multiple column when any one can be null in sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12094479/how-to-set-unique-constraint-over-multiple-column-when-any-one-can-be-null-in-sq)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a unique [`partial index`](https://www.sqlite.org/partialindex.html) for `first_name` and `last_name` only when suffix is null:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_people ON people(first_name, last_name) 
WHERE suffix IS NULL;
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=576bf7713a1cb4f46cc5f9ae1e9cc840).

If your version of SQLite is 3.31.0+, you could create a generated column which returns an empty string when `suffix` is `null` and use it in the unique constraint instead of `suffix`:

```
CREATE TABLE people (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    last_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    suffix TEXT,
    str_suffix GENERATED ALWAYS AS (COALESCE(suffix, '')),
    UNIQUE (first_name, last_name, str_suffix)
);
```

Comment: The partial index is cool! Thank you for teaching me something new.

Answer (score 1):

Make the default for suffix empty string and set it as not null. That will probably address your issue (NULL is not the same as '', NULL is I don't know, so with the code below you are saying the middle name is empty string, instead of NULL).

```
CREATE TABLE people (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    last_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    suffix TEXT DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (first_name, last_name, suffix)
);
```