# Make SQLite consider nulls indistinct in UNIQUE constraint

Tags: database, sqlite

In SQLite `UNIQUE` constraints `NULL`s are distinct ([source](https://www.sqlite.org/nulls.html)). In my use case I'd like `NULL`s to be indistinct for a particular `UNIQUE` constraint. The following example shows what I want.

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE Foo (Name TEXT NOT NULL, Nullable TEXT, UNIQUE(Name, Nullable));
sqlite> INSERT INTO Foo(Name, Nullable) VALUES('foo', 'bar');
sqlite> INSERT INTO Foo(Name, Nullable) VALUES('foo', 'bar'); -- Errors as expected
Runtime error: UNIQUE constraint failed: Foo.Name, Foo.Nullable (19)
sqlite> INSERT INTO Foo(Name) VALUES('baz');
sqlite> INSERT INTO Foo(Name) VALUES('baz'); -- I want this to error, but it doesn't
```

It appears that [PostgreSQL has support for this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS) with `NULLS NOT DISTINCT`, but this syntax doesn't work in SQLite. So, I'm wondering how I can get this behavior in SQLite.

Comment: Why not reserve a special value and use that instead of NULL? Using non-standard features (= less simple DB) must provide an additional worth.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set unique constraint over multiple columns when any one can be null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12094479/how-to-set-unique-constraint-over-multiple-columns-when-any-one-can-be-null)

Comment: @user4157124 I think that the answers are the same, but the question is different. I was hoping I could actually make SQLite treat NULLS as indistinct like you can in PostgreSQL, but it seems that isn't possible.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert `NULL` values to some value to make it count in unique index.

Create your unique index in a following way:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `idx_my_unique` ON Foo (
    Name,
    IFNULL(Nullable, '')
);
```

Of course this has a limitation that empty strings and NULL will be treat as the same value from the uniqueness point of view. If this does not limit you, you can choose this design.

Otherwise you need to re-design your table in a way unique index is used over columns without `NULL` value.

Comment: If empty string should be distinct from NULL in this regard, most likely it should be possible to come up with a dummy string that could be used instead of empty strings here.

Comment: @PChemGuy : yes, that's good point. Some `UNIQUE` non-likely to be submitted by real users string can be used instead.